# Re-writing a python program into VB, how to sort CSV?

Tags: python, vb.net, excel, sorting, csv

About a year back, I wrote a little program in python that basically automates a part of my job (with quite a bit of assistance from you guys!)  However, I ran into a problem.  As I kept making the program better and better, I realized that Python did not want to play nice with excel, and (without boring you with the details suffice to say xlutils will not copy formulas) I NEED to have more access to excel for my intentions.

So I am starting back at square one with VB (2010 Express if it helps.)  The only programming course I ever took in my life was on it, and it was pretty straight forward so I decided I'd go back to it for this.  Unfortunately, I've forgotten much of what I had learned, and we never really got this far down the rabbit hole in the first place.  So, long story short I am trying to:

1)  Read data from a .csv structured as so:

```
    41,332.568825,22.221759,-0.489714,eow
    42,347.142926,-2.488763,-0.19358,eow
    46,414.9969,19.932693,1.306851,r
    47,450.626074,21.878299,1.841957,r
    48,468.909171,21.362568,1.741944,r
    49,506.227269,15.441723,1.40972,r
    50,566.199838,17.656284,1.719818,r
    51,359.069935,-11.773073,2.443772,l
    52,396.321911,-8.711589,1.83507,l
    53,423.766684,-4.238343,1.85591,l
```

2)  Sort that data alphabetically by column 5
3)  Then selecting only the ones with an "l" in column 5, sort THOSE numerically by column 2 (ascending order) AND copy them to a new file called coil.csv
4)  Then selecting only the ones that have an "r" in column 5, sort those numerically by column 2 (descending order) and copy them to the SAME file coil.csv (appended after the others obviously)

After all of that hoopla I wish to get out:

```
    51,359.069935,-11.773073,2.443772,l
    52,396.321911,-8.711589,1.83507,l
    53,423.766684,-4.238343,1.85591,l
    50,566.199838,17.656284,1.719818,r
    49,506.227269,15.441723,1.40972,r
    48,468.909171,21.362568,1.741944,r
    47,450.626074,21.878299,1.841957,r
    46,414.9969,19.932693,1.306851,r
```

I realize that this may be a pretty involved question, and I certainly understand if no one wants to deal with all this bs, lol.  Anyway, some full on code, snippets, ideas or even relevant links would be GREATLY appreciated.  I've been, and still am googling, but it's harder than expected to find good reliable information pertaining to this.

P.S. Here is the piece of python code that did what I am talking about (although it created two seperate files for the lefts and rights which I don't really need) - if it helps you at all.

```
msgbox(msg="Please locate your survey file in the next window.")
mainfile = fileopenbox(title="Open survey file")
toponame = boolbox(msg="What is the name of the shots I should use for topography? Note: TOPO is used automatically",choices=("Left","Right"))

fieldnames = ["A","B","C","D","E"]
surveyfile = open(mainfile, "r")
left_file = open("left.csv",'wb')
right_file = open("right.csv",'wb')
coil_file = open("coil1.csv","wb")


reader = csv.DictReader(surveyfile, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter=",")
left_writer = csv.DictWriter(left_file, fieldnames + ["F"], delimiter=",")
sortedlefts = sorted(reader,key=lambda x:float(x["B"]))

surveyfile.seek(0,0)

right_writer = csv.DictWriter(right_file, fieldnames + ["F"], delimiter=",")
sortedrights = sorted(reader,key=lambda x:float(x["B"]), reverse=True)

coil_writer = csv.DictWriter(coil_file, fieldnames, delimiter=",",extrasaction='ignore')

for row in sortedlefts:
    if row["E"] == "l" or row["E"] == "cl+l":
        row['F'] = '%s,%s' % (row['B'], row['D'])
    left_writer.writerow(row)
    coil_writer.writerow(row)   

for row in sortedrights:
    if row["E"] == "r":
    row['F'] = '%s,%s' % (row['B'], row['D'])
        right_writer.writerow(row)
    coil_writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Yes, they were typos.  Also, this is just one piece of the program.  A macro would not help me much.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following you.  Let me know what if there is anything I can do to be clearer.

Comment: Macros are not supported with the express edition.

Answer (score 0):

One option you  have is to start with a class to hold the fields.  This allows you to override the ToString method to facilitate the output. Then, it's a fairly simple matter of reading each line and assigning the values to a list of the class.  In your case you'll want the extra step of making 2 lists sorting one descending and combining them:

```
Class Fields

    Property A As Double = 0
    Property B As Double = 0
    Property C As Double = 0
    Property D As Double = 0
    Property E As String = ""
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Join({A.ToString, B.ToString, C.ToString, D.ToString, E}, ",")
    End Function
End Class

Function SortedFields(filename As String) As List(Of Fields)
    SortedFields = New List(Of Fields)
    Dim test As New List(Of Fields)
    Dim sr As New IO.StreamReader(filename)
    Using sr As New IO.StreamReader(filename)
        Do Until sr.EndOfStream
            Dim fieldarray() As String = sr.ReadLine.Split(","c)
            If fieldarray.Length = 5 AndAlso Not fieldarray(4)(0) = "e"c Then
                If fieldarray(4) = "r" Then
                    test.Add(New Fields With {.A = Double.Parse(fieldarray(0)), .B = Double.Parse(fieldarray(1)), .C = Double.Parse(fieldarray(2)), .D = Double.Parse(fieldarray(3)), .E = fieldarray(4)})
                Else
                    SortedFields.Add(New Fields With {.A = Double.Parse(fieldarray(0)), .B = Double.Parse(fieldarray(1)), .C = Double.Parse(fieldarray(2)), .D = Double.Parse(fieldarray(3)), .E = fieldarray(4)})
                End If
            End If
        Loop
    End Using
    SortedFields = SortedFields.OrderBy(Function(x) x.B).Concat(test.OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.B)).ToList
End Function
```

One simple way of writing the data to a csv file is to use the IO.File.WriteAllLines methods and the ConvertAll method of the List:

```
IO.File.WriteAllLines(" coil.csv", SortedFields("textfile1.txt").ConvertAll(New Converter(Of Fields, String)(Function(x As Fields) x.ToString)))
```

You'll notice how the ToString method facilitates this quite easily.

If the class will only be used for this you do have the option to make all the fields string.